# what make ex.Response returns null

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, webexception

I'm scanning a single url that has many paths example: `http://url.com/path1` to `1000`. Sometimes I get a WebException but in my catch block, it will throw a `NullReferenceException` error if I don't use the line

```
if (x.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && x.Response != null)
```

So my question is this: Does code below fix the error or just ignore it?

And one more thing sometimes no error sometimes error but most off the time will error but if use the code below everything works just fine.

```
catch (WebException x)
{
    if (x.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && x.Response != null)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)x.Response;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
           listBox3.Items.add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does code below fix the error or just ignore it

it is fine to check that response is null or not. it is the right way to go, as response can be null.

and in what cases response can be null, this is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) says

> If a response is available from the Internet resource, a WebResponse
>   instance that contains the error response from an Internet resource;
>   otherwise, null.

Comment: So my problems is mystery?

Comment: sorry, didn't get your question. i have answered for your question

Comment: help me please I'm really new to this

Comment: i have already answered @terrala7. is there something else that you want to ask?

Comment: is this code necessary `&& x.Response != null` because without that i will never get any error

Comment: yes it is necessory. i have mentioned the reason for that in my answer. if you don't implement this check you will get exception whenever it is null./

Comment: server is not giving any response, that is why it is null. see the exception details you are getting.

Comment: if so why if `(x.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)` only this code is removed only the i got the error?

Comment: check status will be null. you should change it like this if (x.Status!= null && x.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && x.Response != null)

Comment: ok so i will miss some url right? example code check `http://url/path90` than server did not send response(null) back to the code than code just skip it right?

Comment: is this the best method to check url is there any better function to use?

Comment: ops wait is my theory right or i misunderstood how the null check works?

Comment: for availability of url this is the usual method to do so.

Comment: i need to check 302 301 403 status too so i cant bare with the skip :(

Comment: oh btw i tried to add the null url to the listbox too but nothing show up